# Unable to save json data using python and selenium

Tags: python, api, selenium

I am trying to save json data from https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY. The data.json file is empty. Here is the code

```
import time, json

from selenium import webdriver
 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
 
driver.get(url)
 
time.sleep(5)

button = driver.find_element_by_id("rawdata-tab")
 
button.click()


data = driver.find_element_by_class_name("data").text

d = json.loads(data)

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dumps(d, default=lambda o: '<not serializable>')


time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```

Can't find where I am going wrong, is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Ok, what's wrong here is that your URL, i.e. `"https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"` results in a `json` directly as it is an API call. Now, `button = driver.find_element_by_id("rawdata-tab")` this is a selenium code that finds an element in html code with `id="rawdata-tab"` and clicks it but there is not html or webpage here. So, basically there is no point of using selenium here.

Comment: forget json and just `f.write(data)`

Comment: `json.dump` is for writing a file, `json.dumps` just returns the string.

Comment: Can you share the browser_base url?

Comment: @diggusbickus i took your suggestion and modified the code, able to save data in text file 
`with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)


time.sleep(5)

driver.close()`

Comment: you can name your file `data.json` it's a regular json file.

Comment: @diggusbickus got it  thank you. Is there a better way to get this done without using selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a user-agent to your request headers

```
import requests
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.2.1; Mobile; rv:32.0) Gecko/32.0 Firefox/32.0'}
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

As, I have mentioned in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69932231/unable-to-save-json-data-using-python-and-selenium#comment123619992_69932231), selenium is used for web scraping or more generally mimicking human actions on webpages. But your URL doesn't results in a webpage.
Now, from what I understand, try this instead:

```
import json, requests

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
 
response = requests.get(url)

d = response.json()

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dumps(d, default=lambda o: '<not serializable>')
```

As your url already results in json, here I am just using `requests` to get it and it results in a valid json which you can then write however you want to a file.

> PS: Try to understand whatever you're writing in code as this will help you debug, otherwise you are always going to get stuck somewhere.

Comment: thank you for your input. I understood the above code and tried it. But it does nothing no errors nothing